# Check multiple git repo head revisions

Tags: git

I have dozens of git repos on my machine, origins either GitHub or BitBucket.  I would like a tool that shows me if all of the origins are up to date to date with the local, or to put it another way, I want to see at a glance if I have working set changes, or un-pushed commits across multiple repos and all branches therein.  Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 1):

Well one that I use is [Source Tree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) by altassian. 
It has a GUI for that and can group, and show a quick glance of your repos.

Bad thing is that it's not available on linux.

Maybe others can guide you as well.